# How to get unstuck from blocks if world can't be loaded?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

So I was playing a modpack called Roguelike Adventures and Dungeons and when fighting a dragon, he somehow pushed me into blocks.

I tried to get out but I couldn't mine or build any blocks. It was basically like an xray glitch. I had no other ideas but to turn off the game, so I did. I quit the world and joined back in but when it got to Loading Chunks it said "Internal Server Shutting Down". After it shut down, I got a prompt saying that there were "Illegal Coordinates" (or something like that) and since then I cannot load in to my world.

Is there any way to fix my coordinates without me being able to load the world?

Answer (score 1):

Without editing the world with something such as [MCEdit](https://www.mcedit.net/), you won't be able to get back in. You're currently in a state where your actual character is not in the position the game thinks it is, and it can only reset this if you're not in blocks - find the coordinates you're at in-game (if at all possible) and remove the blocks underneath it in a 5x5x5 area, and you should be able to play again.

Comment: I cant seem to find MCEdit for 1.12.2 if there is any version for 1.12.2 please link it.

Comment: The 1.11 version should function with it - however, since you have a modded version of the game, you should create a copy of your world first in case you mess up. The majority of blocks will be pink/black squares as MCEdit won't recognize them, but as long as you know the coordinates that shouldn't matter. @DeepPlayzYT

Comment: Won't MCEdit also let you directly edit the player's coordinate data as an alternative?

Comment: It might do - I'm unaware of that aspect of it, but I'll test and get back to you on that one @Venoda

Comment: I may be misremembering. I haven't used MCEdit since back in the beta days!

Comment: Thank all of you for your comments but after open my world in mcedit i get this error saying Unhandeld Exepction  https://imgur.com/a/UfwGMYb